# SharePoint 2013: Custom master-page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, custom-masterpage, design-manager

I've a requirement for master-page.

1. I'm looking for a step by step blog/read/MSDN to design custom master-page. I've found few reads online but it doesn't provide everything. I need to cover everything that can be changed e.g. Ribbon, Suite, Search, Body etc.
2. 2nd phase will involve making it responsive. What all methods can be used e.g. media queries, device channel panels etc. I've to target IE8.

Notes:

1. SharePoint 2013 EE
2. Designing must be done using Design Manager

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use Shareboot follow bellow link you will get the answer in detail.

http://www.topsharepoint.com/shareboot-responsive-sharepoint-2013-theme/

here you can download the zip file complete files

http://www.topsharepoint.com/freethemes/ShareBootV003.zip

Comment: Thank you. :) I'm not supposed to take any third party code and use. I can refer and write my own.